# TFF: Does TFF support any other models except neurel networks?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to make a comparison between different federated learning frameworks.
When looking on the TFF site, I could not find any information about which models are supported.
Looking at the ['model' API](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model) they only talked about weights,...

Am I missing something or can TFF not be used for other models except neural networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFF has conceptually two levels of API:

The low level [**Federated Core**](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/federated_core) API of TFF supports arbitrary computation on scalars, vectors, matrices, etc; doing anything TensorFlow can do. The notion of a model is not inherit at this level and there is greater freedom. The [Custom Federated Algorithms, Part 1: Introduction to the Federated Core](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_1) tutorial is a good introduction.

The higher level [**Federated Learning**](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/federated_learning) API is built on top of the Federated Core API and starts to add assumptions/constraints. For example the provided FedAvg algorithm implementation mostly expects backprop style training on a model's forward pass. Other federated algorithms are definitely interesting, but may need to be build on the Federated Core API.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Keras models, which is not limited to neural networks.

A Keras model can be converted to the [`tff.learning.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model) format using [`tff.learning.from_keras_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/from_keras_model), and this can be used together with the higher level computations like [`tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process). For an example of logistic regression in TFF, see for instance https://github.com/google-research/federated/tree/master/optimization/stackoverflow_lr

I also second the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67217887/858684), you can write essentially anything if needed.